# Перенаправление 404 ошибки на другой домен с сохранением пути (wild card)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http-status-code-404

Есть старый сайт который передвинут на домен `old.domainname.com`. Есть новый сайт на домене `domainname.com`. На сайте 8000 статей и база работает медленно, поэтому база разделена на 2х провайдеров и 2/3 на старом сайте и 1/3 на новом. Всё проиндексировано гуглом и он регулярно шлёт на старые статьи, но у них другой адрес сейчас.

Возник вопрос, как написать `.htaccess rule` так чтобы если не найден документ на сайте `domainname.com`, то запрос перенаправляется на `old.domainname.com` с сохранением пути, то есть wild card?

В общем задача решена. Как.
 1. .htaccess оставили как есть. Поскольку wordpress на котором собран сайт сам обрабатывает 404, какой смысл изобретать велосипед.
 2. В 404.php, который находится в теме вордпресса, до вызова функции
    get_header() пишем

```
$t344 = 'Location:old.domainname.com'.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
header('Status: 301'); 
header( $t344 ); 
exit();
```

И это работает. Без промежуточной переменной $t344 скрипт отправлял на корень old.domainname.com

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если под документами подразумеваются реально существующие файлы и каталоги (то есть урлы вида `http://domainname.com/1.html`, где `1.html` - статика, или `http://domainname.com/section/`, где `section` - существующий каталог), то можно через `RewriteRule`:

```
RewriteEngine  On
RewriteBase    /
RewriteCond    %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond    %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule    ^(.*)$  http://old.domainname.com/$1 [L]
```

Всё остальное проще анализировать в обработчике 404, как-то так, например:

```
ErrorDocument /404.php
```

и:

```
<?php

if( !can_handle_request() )
{
    header( 'Status: 301' );
    header( 'Location: http://old.domainname.com'.$SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] );
    exit();
}
```

---

> второй я знаю, но он показывает 404 браузеру,

Только в том случае, если вы сами это делаете своими руками. Вот пример, создаю /404.php, направляю туда `ErrorDocument` и пишу в нём:

```
<?php

    header( 'Status: 301' );
    header( 'Location: http://ya.ru/' );
```

Работает так (где тут 404?):

```
[12:58:03] www $ wget -S http://127.0.0.1/ssdsd
--2015-06-02 12:58:06--  http://127.0.0.1/ssdsd
Подключение к 127.0.0.1:80... соединение установлено.
HTTP-запрос отправлен. Ожидание ответа... 
  HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
  Date: Tue, 02 Jun 2015 09:58:06 GMT
  Server: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
  Location: http://ya.ru/
  Content-Length: 0
  Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
  Connection: Keep-Alive
  Content-Type: text/x-perl
Адрес: http://ya.ru/ [переход]
--2015-06-02 12:58:06--  http://ya.ru/
Распознаётся ya.ru (ya.ru)… 93.158.134.3, 213.180.193.3, 213.180.204.3, ...
Подключение к ya.ru (ya.ru)|93.158.134.3|:80... соединение установлено.
HTTP-запрос отправлен. Ожидание ответа... 
  HTTP/1.1 200 Ok
  ...
```

Comment: спасибо за ответ.
первый способ предпочтительнее, второй я знаю, но он показывает 404 браузеру, что нежелательно - гугл может сказать что сайт весь в 404 - это не очень подходит. когда старый сайт заново проиндексируется гуглом, то можно так сделать, да, но сейчас желательно первым способом без 404 обработчика.  
и тут проблемка - с этим правилом, что вы написали он всё отправляет на старый сайт. с чем это может быть связано? то есть даже domainname.com реврайтит на old.domainname.com

Comment: "*Если под документами подразумеваются реально существующие файлы и каталоги*" - это условие выполнено? Уверен что нет.

Comment: *второй я знаю, но он показывает 404 браузеру* - с чего бы? См. дополнение ответа.

Comment: ErrorDocument /404.php - выдает 500 ошибку
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php - ошибку не выдаёт.  

404.php - пропущено закрытие ?> - добавил, но почему-то не работает. просто запускаю domainname.com/404.php - белый лист.   перехода на old.domainname.com/404.php не происходит.  
попытка запустить domainname.com/123 выдает стандартную 404 страницу.

Comment: И? Разбирайтесь, чините.  Как сделать правильно я написал, а как вы это делаете - другой вопрос.

Comment: сайт работает нормально. ваш код второго варианта (который пришлось исправить) по идее должен работать, но не работает. первый вариант вызвал 500 ошибку. что чинить? в любом случае спасибо.

Comment: Так что я-то сказать могу? Смотрите логи сервера, проверяйте права на файлы, или что вы обычно делаете, когда ищете что не работает. У меня нет ни доступа к вашему серверу, ни мотивации делать эту работу :)

Comment: в общем задача решена. как.  
1. .htaccess оставили как есть. поскольку wordpress на котором собран сайт сам обрабатывает 404, какой смысл велосипедить.  
2. 404.php который находится в теме вордпресса, до вызова функции get_header() пишем  

$t344 = 'Location: http://old.domainname.com'.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    header( 'Status: 301' );
    header( $t344 );
    exit();  

и это работает.
без промежуточной переменной отправляло на корень old.domainname.com

вопрос вожно закрывать.